# Is it true that for all large enough integer $n$, there is a integer $m$ such that $n+im$ is a Gaussian prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, gaussian-integers

Let $n$ denote a positive integer greater than $6$. Is it known whether there is always an integer $m$ such that $n+im$ is a Gaussian prime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This statement is equivalent to :

> For every large enough positive integer $n$, there is a positive integer $m$ such that $m^2+n^2$ is prime.

This follows from the Bunyakovsky conjecture , but as far as I know it is unknown whether this is the case.

Comment: Thank you. What is known for the weaker proposition "for all large enough positive integer $n$, there exists a complex number $z$ such that $\vert z\vert<n$ and both $n-z$ and $n+z$ are Gaussian primes"?

Comment: @SylvainJulien Interesting ! Why not ask a new question ?

Comment: Ok, I'll do so.